# find min, max ratio to interpolate triangle points by two angles based on arc

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, interpolation

**Summary:**

[image: Animation]

We have parametric $j$ - mininal angle in radians, $k$ - maximal angle in radians and $r$ - arc radius, $d$ - arc diameter, $C$ - center

**Green $45\deg$ arc:**

$Ax=Cx+cos(j)*r$, $Ay=Cy+sin(j)*r$

$Bx=Cx+cos(k)*r$, $By=Cy+sin(k)*r$

**Red $\triangle DEC$ triangle:**

to limit it with given min, max angles i just lineary interpolate positions of edges points (D and E)
$$Dx=Cx-r+d*Xmin, Ex=Cx-r+d*Xmax; Dy=Ey=Cy-r$$
and normalized ratio is calculated next:
$$Xmin=\frac{j - u}{v-u}; Xmax=\frac{k - u}{v-u};$$

where $u=3*\frac{\pi}{2}$, $v=4*\frac{\pi}{2}$

**Issue:** interpolated points positions of triangle have same angles as green arc but goes outside arc bounds a little bit sometimes (horizontally).
How to calculate proper interpolation ratios to always keep red triangle in bounds of arc?

Comment: That is, you want $C$, $A$, $D$ to stay aligned, and the same for $C$, $B$, $E$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points $A$, $C$, $D$ are aligned if there exists a number $t$ such that:
$$
D=C+(A-C)t.
$$
Insert there $D_y=C_y-r$ and solve for $t$, to find
$$
t=-{r\over A_y-C_y}.
$$
Then substitute back into the first equation to get
$$
D_x=C_x-(A_x-C_x){r\over A_y-C_y}.
$$
Do the same for points $B$, $C$, $E$.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be right, animation: https://i.imgur.com/8LyZZpG.gif

Comment: @not-a-real Which coordinates did you use in that animation, for $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @not-a-real Sorry, there was a typo: I wrote $B_y$ instead of $C_y$. Formulas are correct now.

Comment: Thanks, it works as intended. Just one more question, originally i doesn't need $A$ and $B$ points and the arc itself, so is $Dx=Cx-cos(j) * r / sin(j)$ most simplified equation?

Comment: @not-a-real Yes, right: you can simplify the equations like that.